# What does "boo-boo face" mean, and how did it originate?

Tags: meaning, colloquialisms, neologisms

What does "boo-boo face" mean? I've found it many times before but can't understand it. Is it a recent expression? What is the etymology of *boo-boo face*?

Comment: What does your dictionary show for the meaning of boo-boo?

Comment: We ask that you check a dictionary before asking basic questions such as these. Please see the help section on how to ask questions.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you please add some context for the use of _boo-boo face_, to help us understand what you are asking?

Comment: That face you make right before you cry. In my experience people use it mostly when referring to younglings that have just suffered a minor physical injury (often regarded as a boo-boo).

Comment: **Boo-hoo** is the sound a small child makes when they cry, usually it's over and done with quickly. You can also use this expression to mock someone's distress if you believe it is trivial. [**Boo-boo**](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&q=boo-boo+meaning&oq=boo-boo+meaning&gs_l=serp.1.0.0j0i30l7j0i5i30l2.214580.215160.0.217943.2.2.0.0.0.0.160.312.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.46.serp..0.2.308.vK-V7ZZO05M) on the other hand is new to me, and I had to look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be, that "boo-boo face" refers to the face someone might make when they've gotten an injury of some kind, a cut or a bruise.  Children and adults will sometimes refer to a small injury as a "boo-boo".